# Extract fit measures from multiple models

Tags: r, extract, lapply, sapply, r-lavaan

I am using the `lavaan` package to run multiple confirmatory factor analysis models from which I want to extract several fit measures ("chisq", "cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"). I know that I can print out these fit measures from one model at a time like this:

```
fitMeasures(firstmodel, fit.measures = c("chisq", "cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"))
fitMeasures(secondmodel, fit.measures = c("chisq", "cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"))
fitMeasures(thirdmodel, fit.measures = c("chisq", "cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"))
```

but is there a way to do all of them in one step? Maybe using the `lapply` or `sapply`?

Comment: `sapply(list(firstmodel, secondmodel, thirdmodel), fitMeasures, c("chisq", "cfi", "rmsea", "srmr"))` will return a matrix, or use `lapply()` for a list.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks @RitchieSacramento